# VBA error : Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I want to look from a column in excel for the names "JOHN", "PETER", "ALAN", "ALI" with only one if statements as you see below. I got an error message Type mismatch.

Can any please help me?

```
Option Explicit

Sub name()

    Dim i As Long, nam As String
    nam = Array("JOHN", "PETER", "ALAN", "ALI")
    For i = 1 To 3000
        If Worksheets("CONTACTS").Cells(i, 1).Value = nam Then
            Worksheets("CONTACTS").Cells(i, 5).Value = "good"
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: So if one of the nam's is in column A then column E should say good...?

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: `nam` is an array. You need to specify which element to match, or you could use the Array's `Filter` function.

Comment: You would have to use `Dim nam() As String` in order to stuff an array into an array of strings. However, once you do that, the `.Cells(i, 1).Value = nam` will not equate a single cell value directly to an array of strings.

Comment: Also, note that `Sub Name()` causes an Expected Expression runtime error for me, due to the fact that `Name` is a reserved word.

Comment: pame o pepas pame pame pokerpepas pameeee !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two issues: first, my excel complains with the array initialization, so i'm using variant instead of string; second, poolie is right - loop through the array. This should be what you want:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
 Dim i As Long, nam As Variant
    nam = Array("JOHN", "PETER", "ALAN", "ALI")
    For i = 1 To 30
        For j = 0 To UBound(nam)
            If Worksheets("CONTACTS").Cells(i, 1).Value = nam(j) Then
                Worksheets("CONTACTS").Cells(i, 5).Value = "good"
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I believe your `nam` is going to have an [LBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx) of `0`, not `1`.

Answer (score 1):

I've reworked your loop through the worksheet cells into a bulk memory operation.

```
Sub name_check()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, a As Long
    Dim nam As Variant, colAs As Variant

    nam = Array("JOHN", "PETER", "ALAN", "ALI")
    i = 3000

    With Worksheets("CONTACTS")
        colAs = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(i, 2).Value2

        For a = LBound(colAs, 1) To UBound(colAs, 1)
            colAs(a, 2) = vbNullString
            For n = LBound(nam) To UBound(nam)
                If UCase(colAs(a, 1)) = nam(n) Then
                    colAs(a, 2) = "good"
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next n
        Next a

        .Cells(1, 5).Resize(i, 1) = Application.Index(colAs, 0, 2)
    End With

End Sub
```

All of the looping and individual variable assignment is done within two variant arrays. Only when those operations are complete are the results returned to the worksheet *en masse*.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be comparing the value to an array. You probably need to use a loop to check if the value in the cell is any of the names you're looking for.

(I'm not a VBA expert so I can't give you the code.)